# Are all controllers in Java, Servlets?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

This is a two part question[Please bear with me]:

Recently someone argued with me that the spring MVC annotation @Controller is a completely different breed and doesnt implement Servlet at any point.

I have been implementing Servlets as Controllers since I was a baby and havent encountered anything else like it(in relation to Java at least).

Question 1: Does @controller have any link to servlet?

Question 2: Are there other mechanisms to implement Request/response without servlet? I know JSP/JSF etc but at the core, they are still servlets so anything not like that.

Comment: No spring used the DispatcherServlet as frontcontroller. And no, you need servlets at some point

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s02.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A servlet is a [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html).

A `@Controller` annotation references the *concept* of a controller, and is independent of `javax.servlet.Servlet`. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) is quite clear (emphasis mine):

> The `@Controller` annotation indicates that a particular class **serves the role of a controller**. Spring does not require you to extend any controller base class or reference the Servlet API. However, you can still reference Servlet-specific features if you need to.

From that, the answer to your title question is: No. (Also you asked about "all controllers in Java", but note that Spring != all of Java.)

Your question about "other methods to implement request/response" is too vague to answer. There are infinite ways to implement anything. You could write a raw HTTP server in Java if you'd like. You could use a different protocol than HTTP entirely. You could do something not network based at all if that was part of your requirements. You could use a different language / framework that isn't Java. Be more specific.

Comment: Thanks!! I agree, my question was way too vague but I actaully got the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Spring mvc dispatch request and response through servlet. It's just common to use servlet specification because it's supported by all servlet containers and you can choice your favorite like Jetty, Tomcat etc.
2. Servlet is just specification how requests, responses, sessions etc can be handeled. But it's not necessary. Look at [netty](http://netty.io/) or similar.

From architectural view, [servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2) and @Controller are similar.

Comment: +1 "From architectural view, servlet and @Controller are similar" - that's the major take home point.

Comment: netty is the answer 2, I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: @ManiacalLaugh If your requirements are very simple you could also consider an xml-rpc implementation like http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/download.html ([Example](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/handlerCreation.html)). Or just use the built-in [`HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) with `URL` connections or whatever other simple client side you want.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Does @controller have any link to servlet?

Controllers are called from the servlet called DispatcherServlet that u configured in ur web.xml file.

Your request first is handled by Dispatcher servlet, and dispatcher servlet decides which controller it should call based on ur url mappings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually springMVC is using Front Controller design pattern to remove the code duplicasy problem. So according to the front controller design pattern we need not have to write more than one servlet that is DispatcherServlet. But i will tell you that every request is going through DispatcherServlet only.